# Concatenating variables in a mongodb update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I'm trying to update a specific field from an array using Mongodb. To do so, i'm trying to use the following code:

```
  db.collection(CG).update(
    { 
      _id : ObjectId(req.params.id) 
    },
    { 
      $set: { "cg." + req.params.index + ".nom" : req.body.nom } 
    }, 
    function (err, result){
        res.json(result);
    }
  );
```

However, this approach doesn't run. A problem rises from this line:

`$set: { "cg." + req.params.index + ".nom" : req.body.nom }`.

If i change this line for:

`$set: { "cg.0.nom" : req.body.nom }`

it runs.

Just to notice... with this line I'm accessing a 'cg' element that have the following structure:

As far as I know there are some solution (using projection) that work over the `.find()` method, but I can't find or adapt to this specific situation.

Any tip/advice/new solution is welcome, thank you.

Comment: @BlakesSeven , you are right! Thank you! :)

Comment: That's why the banner is presented to you to confirm that the linked "question/answer(s)" helped you. It's a common enough JavaScript notation mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var field = "cg." + req.params.index + ".nom"

    db.collection(CG).update(
    { 
      _id : ObjectId(req.params.id) 
    },
    { 
      $set: { field : req.body.nom } 
    }, 
    function (err, result){
        res.json(result);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Nope. JavaScript "stringifies" keys, so the update statement would be taken to mean `"$set": { "field": req.body.nom }`, rather than interpolate the variable content into the object.